# Concat ajax success respone

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax request success function

```
function(res){
   var proposedValue='res.'+ res.ProposedFor;
   $('#MyDynamicDropdown').val(proposedValue);
}
```

Here, proposedValue does return

> res.AreaId

But it doesn't set my value in the dropdown.
If I use

```
 $('#MyDynamicDropdown').val(res.AreaId);
```

That works fine.But I can't use this because I don't know what has been propose for.
Thanks hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Looks like `proposedValue` is really a string with a value of `'res.AreaId'`.

Comment: Can you use `var proposedValue = res[ res.ProposedFor ];` ?

Comment: It seems very strange that it would return `res.AreaId` for `proposedValue`.

Comment: @epascarello I escaped some complexity in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not build a string and have the engine automatically assume you want that to reference the object that happens to be there.

What you need to do is drop the building of a string and just use bracket notation.

```
$('#MyDynamicDropdown').val(res[res.ProposedFor]);
```

Comment: Well numbers do not have leading zeros.... So however you are storing it needs to be a string, not a number.

Comment: Sorry, I had some previous code which I was missing. It worked as wanted

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "dropdown" is a `<select>` element, you have to specify which `<option>` element in the select you want to set a value on.

I assume you want to set it on the selected option, so I used the :selected selector for you in a small jsfiddle. Let me know if this doesn't answer your question, and you can specify which element you are using.

EDIT: And also, as other has pointed out, make sure you use the right property of the object.

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/8756/)

Answer (score 0):

If i could understand you want to assign an another index of "res" by itself value as an index, I think you can do such as below :

```
    function(res){
       var proposedValue= res[res.ProposedFor];
       $('#MyDynamicDropdown').val(proposedValue);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use eval() function

```
$('#MyDynamicDropdown').val(eval(proposedValue));
```

Comment: Why would you want to use eval?